# When should I use the <<creates>> stereotype in a UML class diagram

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml

I have a very basic question in deed, but I never stopped to think about this.

Well, I was wondering about the correct use of the <<create>> stereotype of UML2.
In this case at the figure bellow, is it right to represent the dependency within the interface, or it must be on the concrete classes that actualy creates the object.

[image: Class Diagram]

I've been digging for sometime and could find nothing but ambiguous or uncomplete information. This link was the best one I was able to find:
http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html

The definition is ok, but it doen't mention anything about interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The interface Orientation depends on the Point class, so it is absolutely valid to present the dependency like this. It is no problem that it is an interface. It depends on the Point class.

Comment: Yes, it depends, but, souldn't I have someting like a general dependency on the interface Orientation (because of the parameters) and then a create dependency on each concretion?

Comment: If you think it's useful, you could add two stereotypes on the depeendency, <<needs>> and <<creates>>. But you are not obliged to present every bit of information in a UML diagram. Each diagram targets to help people understand a part of the system. If you just want to show a compile dependency, then a depends without any stereotype is enough. If you want to show that Orientation serves a a factory of Points, then your diagram is perfect, it points exactly that. Keep in mind that if you include all dependencies in a class diagram then it is likely to become completely unreadable.

Comment: Right... In this case, Orientation is not like a factory, it just creates another Point after doing some calculations based on the two parameters. Maybe I am overthinking this, it is perfectly readable this way. Well, thank you nakosspy =]